# Keep main element after sorting with xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a source xml:

```
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <ns0:Message1>
        <SHPMNT05>
            <IDOC BEGIN="1">
                <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
                    <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
                </EDI_DC40>
                <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
                    <TKNUM>0000046741</TKNUM>
                    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                       <VBELN>1</VBELN>
                       <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
                    </E1EDL20>
                    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                       <VBELN>1</VBELN>
                       <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
                    </E1EDL20>
                </E1EDT20>
            </IDOC>
        </SHPMNT05>
    </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

I'm sorting all E1EDL20 elements with xslt:

```
 <xsl:template match="E1EDT20">
    
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::E1EDL20)]">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    
        <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL20">
            <xsl:sort select="VKORG"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--  Default Template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

But in my result I'm missing the parent E1EDT20 element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <ns0:Message1>
        <SHPMNT05>
            <IDOC BEGIN="1">
                <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
                    <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
                </EDI_DC40>
                <TKNUM>0000046741</TKNUM>
                    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                       <VBELN>1</VBELN>
                       <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
                    </E1EDL20>
                    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                       <VBELN>1</VBELN>
                       <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
                    </E1EDL20>
            </IDOC>
        </SHPMNT05>
    </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

What do I need to put after

```
<xsl:template match="E1EDT20">
```

to keep the element / tag in the output?

Very sorry to bother you with this beginners question but every so often I have to use xslt and I can't find the answer after search for quite some time...

Mike

Comment: `<xsl:sort select="VKORG"/>` I see no `VKORG` in your example.

Comment: Updated the post Michael. Thanks for the info. I've stripped too much from my original xml..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template which matches `E1EDT20` you don't copy the element; you only copy its children.

You should copy the element with `xsl:copy`, and within that, copy its attributes, and then process the child elements:

```
<xsl:template match="E1EDT20">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::E1EDL20)]">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    
      <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL20">
          <xsl:sort select="VKORG"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Conal, perfect! Very happy with it :)

Comment: Actually you don't need the `for-each` statement for the non-`E1EDL20` elements; you can just `<xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::E1EDL20)]"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the content of your template in an `xsl:copy` instruction. You can also shorten it to:

```
<xsl:template match="E1EDT20">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | *[not(self::E1EDL20)]"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL20">
            <xsl:sort select="VKORG"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Much appreciated Michael!